# Scanner does not read text file in run mode

Tags: java

i am trying to deal with this problem without much success. Hope for some help.
From inside my Java program, I am calling an outside executable, which upon completion creates a text (ASCII) file. I am using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("....exe");`
```

Next, I am asking for it to complete before switching

```
int exitValue = p.waitFor();
```

and make sure that exit value is 0.

Right after that, I am creating a Scanner object to read the newly created file:

```
File outputFile = new File(outputFileName);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(outputFile);
```

The file resides in the same folder as the executable, but I am passing a full path to it anyway. 
When I check if I can read the file (`outputFile.canRead()`), the answer is true. 
When I check the length of the file, it returns to me some number > 0, i.e., 440827.
However, when I try to call `scan.hasNextLine()` or even `scan.hasNext()`, the answer is negative.
An interesting fact is that when I run this in NetBeans debug mode, everything works fine. So, my guess is that i am in some sort of a race condition even though I am making precautions to not interrupt the Process's thread.
I tried to insert `Thread.sleep()` statements before calling `nextLine()`, but no result.
Any suggestions, please?

This was the simplified version of the code... Upon requests, here is more detailed processing (spread between 4 classes) - i apologize for several levels of redirections:

```
public class A
{
    private void runEngine()
    {
        try
        {
        // Skip irrelevant stuff - model is an object of class B:            
            model.runEngineIfNeeded(keepInputFiles);
            outputFileTextArea.setText(
                model.processOutput(keepInputFiles, keepOutputFiles));
        //...
        }
        catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

public class B    
{
    public void runEngineIfNeeded(boolean keepInputFiles)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        // exit under some condition, otherwise:
        boolean enginOK = false;

        while(!enginOK)             
             enginOK = createEnginFile(keepInputFiles);
    }
    public boolean createEnginFile(boolean keepFile)
    {
        String engineDir = "C:/data";     
        final String[] cmdArray = {"cmd", "/C", B.EXE_FILENAME};
        // output is a 2-dimensional array of strings
       output = Exec.getSTDERRandSTDOUT(cmdArray, engineDir);

       if (output[1].isEmpty())
            return true; //no exception occur

      // do some data manipulation and...
      return false;
    }

    public String processOutput(boolean keepLoopinInput, boolean keepLoopinOutputs)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException
   {
       String enginOutput = null;

       while (enginOutput == null)
       {
            enginOutput = c.processEnginOutput();  // c is an obj of class C

        if (enginOutput == null)
            createLoopinFile(keepEngineInput);
    }

    return enginOutput;
   }
}

public class Exec
{
    public static String[] getSTDERRandSTDOUT(String[] cmd, String directory)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] output = new String[2]; // 2 string array for output
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);

        if (directory != null) {
            processBuilder.directory(new File(directory));
        }

        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        ExecStreamRedirect stdout = new ExecStreamRedirect(process.getInputStream(), 
                                                           OutputType.STDOUT);

       stdout.start();

       ExecStreamRedirect stderr = new ExecStreamRedirect(process.getErrorStream(),
                                                          OutputType.STDERR);

       stderr.start();
       int waitFor = process.waitFor();

       output[0] = stdout.getSTDOUT().toString();
       output[1] = stderr.getSTDERR().toString();
       return output;
    }
}

class C
{
    public String processEnginOutput(float actKtDLS, boolean keepOutputs)
                throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException,
                       IOException
    { // Read file into Output text area:
        File analysisOutputFile    = new File(outputFileNamePath);
        Scanner scan               = null;
        String scanLine            = "";
        StringBuilder enginOutput = new StringBuilder(
                                        (int) analysisOutputFile.length());
        boolean outputFileOK = false;

        // Must be careful here, possibility for endless loop:
        stop: for (int i = 2000; i < 4000 && !outputFileOK; i+= 100)
        {
            int j = 0; // start counting lines

            try
            {
                if (GenericUtils.waitIfFileIsNotReady(analysisOutputFile, j))
                 // does not exist & readable
                    continue; // go to next iteration

                scan = new Scanner(analysisOutputFile);

                for (; !outputFileOK; j++)
               {
                    scanLine = scan.nextLine();
                    enginOutput.append(scanLine).append("\n\n");

               // .. more logic here;
               }

               // .. more logic here;

               scan.close();

               return enginOutput.toString();
            } // end of try
            catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
            { //EOF reached
                 processEngineDelay(
             "output file is not completly written. Last line read: "
                                 + j + ".  " + scanLine +
                                  ". Wait " + i + " msecs.",
                                   scan,
                                   i);
            }  // continue [stop] with the next loop iteration...
        } // repeat up to 20 times if needed       
    }

    private static void processEngineDelay(String msg, Scanner scan, int i)
                throws InterruptedException
   {
        // to perform error processing
        LOGGER.warning(msg);
        scan.close(); // close scan
        scan = null;
        Thread.sleep(i);
   }
}
```

I think this is it... i apologize - the code is complicated and that was the reason why i initially provided simplified version only. Hopefully i listed all relevant portions

Comment: Decent description, but actual code would be even better.

Comment: Please post the format of the file. At first, is it a "text" file?

Comment: Yes, it is ASCII text... the file is pretty long, and the reason I am preferring to read it with Scanner is, because, i am reading different portions of the file for different purposes: a) Portions of it populate the GUI text area (that portion i am retrieving with nextLine(), line by line)  b) in a middle of it is a table, that I am using to create a chart and do some calculations (I am using nextFloat()s to read that portion)... switching between different scanner methods are big convenience, if I can only make it work :)

Comment: Did you try placing the Thread.sleep() before creating the Scanner?

Comment: drob, you actually solved my problem, thank you! I realized that I was putting sleep statements **after** scanner was created (after hasNextLine() failed), but not before. Putting it before (of course, now it makes sense), helped. However, my next question is why running process uninterrupted did not do the trick and how much sleep time I should pass? My program should run on several OSs, 32 and 64 bits, so I do not know what arbitrary number for sleep to use... is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: @user2116891: your doubt has to be expressed in a new question, not at the end of this.

Comment: Please paste in the relevant code in one piece.

Comment: Thanks for keeping this post alive. I do not understand the comment of entering a new question since it is still the original question which was not answered completey in my mind (that is, i believe there is a better solution, although i may be wrong of cousre). In any case, it has never been solved by me as I moved to other tasks, but i would try to find and reproduce the cod here. Please be mindful that the whole processing is spread between 3 different classes and most of the code cannot be shown due to IP restrictions, but here is what it looks like:

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot go back to edit the previous comment - @ithofm - i posted the relevant code i believe... if it will help you find a better solution, will be very greatful. thanks.

Comment: @tulu - you're closing your previous scanner in the same function that implements the call to Thread.sleep().  This means that the scanner from the previous iteration of your loop is only ever closed if the next iteration fails.  I don't know why, but this might cause issues with cached file handles.  Have you tried making sure the scanner is closed on each iteration?

Comment: @Jules, sorry i cut it out accidentally, there actually is a scan.close() statement in the main loop, I just edited it in. If the file is read to the end, there is no need in more iterations - the function returns after scan.close(). It is only if the file was not completely written by the executable ran in previous step, when i am attempting to go back, and after waiting for some _arbitrary_ time I attempt to read it through again... And, I have again, _arbitrary_ limited my reading to 20 attempts as to avoid infinite loop...

Comment: Continue, was too long: OK, this so far works (has been in production for over a year), but what still bothers me is that this solution is, well,  _arbitrary_... I am guessing with number of attempts and with the length of the sleep time which now is set to 2 sec initially, gradually increasing to 4 sec by 100 ms with each iteration.. I would prefer a cleaner solution, if there is one, please